# [ApiResponse.Failure.Exception](message=java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to display a wallet to my app using retrofit. Im getting an error when the value of the wallet is an empty string or empty array. I want to put an temporary value on the currentBalance and subscriberId to not recieve the error:

this is the sample output of postman that is successful

```
{
"wallet": {
    "subscriberId": 123123123,
    "currentBalance": "5,000.00"
    }
}
```

this is the output when the error is occuring when the value of wallet is an empty string:

```
{
"wallet": [],

}
```

already tried this method but still receiving an error:

```
@WorkerThread
fun getUserLoadWallet(
    getUserResponsePostData: GetUserResponsePostData,
    sessionId: String,
    onStart: ()->Unit,
    onSuccess: ()->Unit,
    onError: (String)->Unit
) = flow {


    var headers = HashMap<String, String>()
    headers.put("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=$sessionId")
    Log.d("INFO", "Get User Load Wallet PHPSESSID=$sessionId")
    Log.d("INFO", "Get User Load Wallet $getUserResponsePostData")
    portalEngineService.getUserLoadWallet(headers = headers, getUserResponsePostData = getUserResponsePostData)
        .suspendOnSuccess {
            Log.d("INFO", "Wallet User Profile: $data")
            val updatedResponse = if (data.wallet == null){
                data.copy(wallet = Wallet(subscriberId = 0, currentBalance = "0.00"))
            }else{
                data
            }
            emit(updatedResponse)
        }
        .onError {
            Log.d("INFO", "Get User Load Wallet error: ${message()}")
            onError(message())
        }
        .onException {
            Log.d("INFO", "Get User Load Wallet exception: ${message()}")
            onError(message())
        }
}.onStart { onStart() }.onCompletion { onSuccess() }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

Comment: The value of an empty wallet is **NOT** an empty string (based on the example you provided), but rather an empty array. Why are you checking for nullability when you know the value of an empty wallet is an empty array? Why not just do: if (data.wallet.isEmpty())

Comment: already tried isEmpty but its showing Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:

Comment: tried this but not working: 

data class Wallet(
    @SerializedName("subscriberId") val subscriberId: Long,
    @SerializedName("currentBalance") var currentBalance: String
) {
    fun isEmpty(): Boolean {
        return subscriberId.toInt() == 0 && currentBalance == "0.00"
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Because the API is returning wallet as an array (see `[]`) but you are deserializing it as an object.

You have two choices :

1. making your API consistent (make sure it's not returning responses different responses types for a same endpoint)
2. Implement polymorphic deserialization: check this [Polymorphic deserialization with kotlinx.serialization in Kotlin/Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66554036/polymorphic-deserialization-with-kotlinx-serialization-in-kotlin-native)